# Shortest Path Between Points for Airborne Travel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, arcgis-10.3, shortest-path

I work for an aerial surveying firm and have a point shapefile of every location we need to fly over to survey. There are approximately 500 features in this dataset. I would like to determine the optimum flight path so I may fly over each site once. I do not need/ want to use a road network. I have ArcGIS 10.3.1 and every extension.

Comment: You could probably do something like a best route, but you'd have to create lines between every point to create ways on which a route is analysed / created: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005w000000

Comment: I believe that it would be better to tackle this using a raster. Since you are not looking for a "network" and if you do not have harsh restriction of flying routes, rather you have flying zones - so you should treat the aerial space as a surface. Have a look on the [distance toolset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Distance_tools/009z00000014000000/), and in particular on the cost-distance tool (found within the toolset)

Comment: If there's no restrictions on flying directly between all points, I'd be inclined to use best route as suggested by @mapBaker. Creating lines between all the points is a fairly trivial task, and if further points are added for future flights you just add lines for those points and run the analysis again.

Comment: I am having trouble creating lines between every point. I used the Point to Line tool in Arc but it does not create lines between all points. Is there a simple way to do this? Also, Is there a tool that identifies the "Next nearest point"? I was hoping there is something similar to "Near" tool in ArcGIS without referencing a point that has been used in the analysis already.